# «Кто ими будет» – можно ли такую конструкцию употребить?

Tags: выбор-слов

«...считаю, что Крыму нужны профессиональные и эффективные парламентарии в Госдуме. Кто ими будет, решать крымчанам». В данном предложении смущает фраза «кто ими будет». Неправильная конструкция? Как можно заменить?

Comment: Можно заменить на "Кто ими станут". Но можно и оставить.

Comment: А можно ли буквально "решить" за кого-то, что он _будет эффективным и профессиональным_ (парламентарием или кем-то другим)? Можно лишь выбрать парламентария как такового. Я бы предложил "кто это будет...".

Answer (score 1):

А что в ней неправильного? Вас смущает то, что слово «ими»
стоит в творительном падеже? Ну тогда и «я стану космонавтом» нельзя говорить.
Только, после слова «будет» я бы поставил тире.

Comment: Желательно в ответе пояснить выбор тире, иначе это будет всего лишь ваше мнение, но не решение, обоснованное какими-то правилами. Также было бы неплохо, если бы вы объяснили выбор Т.п., ведь он не всегда применяется. Впрочем, это мои личные пожелания для  такого ответа, который можно было бы считать качественным :)

Comment: Поясняю что хочу. Вопрос был не про тире. Если автор вопроса меня спросит про тире, то я ему отвечу.

Comment: Так вы и про Т.п. ничего не пояснили. И почему автор должен  верить вам на слово, что тире можно поставить. А вдруг правила запрещают это? Если уж что-то утверждать, то делать надо это ответственно, не так ли?

Comment: У меня нет принципа, обязывающего меня обосновывать что-либо из моих ответов. Я считаю, что люди должны верить мне наслово, а если не верят, то должны повторять про себя, пока не начнут верить.

Comment: Jim Korbett, мне бы очень хотелось поверить вам "на слово", но вы же это слово пишете неверно. Так как же вам верить?